# Calculation groups without a measure

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to apply this trick from Bas in which he switches between absolute values and % of total : https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=UnG0u8J0pSc

However, this solution doesn't quite work for me for a very good reason : I am not using a measure but a bare column in the context as Y value, thus the SELECTEDMEASURE() cannot work.

Thus my question, how may I use such a lovely trick to print raw value vs % without having a measure in the context please ?

Here is the code :

```
DIVIDE ( SELECTEDMEASURE(), CALCULATE ( SELECTEDMEASURE(), REMOVEFILTERS('ConsolidatedCapacityPlan'[Project category]) ) )
```

Here is a summary of my fields :

[image: Summary of fields]

Thanks in advance for your help,

Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

No

> Calculation groups work with explicit DAX measures. In this example,
> Sales is an explicit measure already created in the model. Calculation
> groups do not work with implicit DAX measures. For example, in Power
> BI implicit measures are created when a user drags columns onto
> visuals to view aggregated values, without creating an explicit
> measure.

[Calculation groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/calculation-groups?view=asallproducts-allversions)

And creating explicit measures and hiding the source columns is a basic best-practice.  For instance Excel also requires explicit DAX measures.